# how to replace an email in java through a method

Tags: java

first time I've tried this. I need to be able to replace an email for subclass Student and sublass Teacher after an email has been inputted, I have a parent class and superclass which is where I believe I need to add my changeEmail method. I may be a way off here but can I use stringBuilder or is there an easier way? Real noob when it comes to this.

---

SUBCLASS -

```
  public class Teacher extends Member
  {

  private String qualifications;


 public Teacher(String name, String email, String qualifications)
 {
 super(name, email);
 this.qualifications = qualifications;
 }


 public String getQualifications()
 {
    return qualifications;
 }


 public String toString()
 {

    StringBuffer details = new StringBuffer();
    details.append(super.getName());
    details.append(' ');

    if(qualifications != null && qualifications.trim().length() > 0) {
        details.append("(" + qualifications + ")");
        details.append(' ');
    }
    details.append(super.getEmail());
    return details.toString();
    }
```

### }

SUBCLASS -

```
    public class Student extends Member
    {

  private int attendance;


  public Student(String name, String email)
  {
  super(name, email);
 this.attendance = 0;
 }


 public int getAttendance()
 {
    return attendance;
 }


 public void markAttendance(int attendance)
 {
    this.attendance += attendance;
 }


 public void print()
 {
    System.out.println(super.getName() + " (" + attendance + ")");
 }
 }
```

---

SUPERCLASS -

```
 public class Member

 {

 private String email;

 private String name;

 public Member(String name, String email)
 {
   this.name = name;
   this.email = email;
 }


 public String getEmail()
 {
    return email;
 }

 public String getName()
 {
    return name;
 }

 public String changeEmail()
 {
    //..........
 }

 }
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. so you just need to add the relevant code in the `changeEmail` method in `Member`? that would be `this.email = email;`.

Comment: hi, yeah I don't l'm not sure what I would need to add to changeEmail to be able to chane a student or teachers email after the input and program has run. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since changeEmail is a public method in the superclass, the subclasses can access it too. `Student` (as well as `Teacher`) ***is*** a `Member`.

```
public String changeEmail(String newEmailAddress) {
    String old = email;
    this.email = newEmailAddress;
    return old;
}
```

What I changed was adding a parameter (String newEmailAddress) and then set the new value to the email instance field.

(EDIT: I updated the answer to return the old email address. I don't know why a method like this would return anything but anyways..)

Comment: well brilliant is a bit of an exaggeration.. but feel free to accept the answer :)

Comment: Notice, definition of the method is with return value of the String type, so you have to add return statement- eg. old or new e-mail

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx  ur right. a little fast. I wonder what should be returned there.. ??

Comment: I dont have any idea, nothing else than void return type is not making a sense to me :D, but let me say, the old mail is fine, eg. for some archive or whatever, can be

Answer (score 0):

That is called `inheritance`, basically if you have some shared variables, you can use some parent class and with the keyword `extends` create some subclasses.

> All subclasses, which inherits the parent class, can have their own class variables, but also are having the parent variables.

In your case you can image the diagram like that- obvious, doesnt?
[image: inheritance diagram]

So...
Parent class `member` is having these class variables:
 - String : mail
 - String : name

You have two subclasses- `Student` and `Teacher`:

`Teacher` class variables:

- qualifications
- mail, name (inherited from parent!)

`Student` class variables:

- attendance
- mail, name (inherited from parent!)

Notice- with the keyword `super` you are calling the constructor (or simply "class" other methods) from the parent, so in `Teacher` and `Student` class, you will call exactly following:

```
public Member(String name, String email) {
   this.name = name;
   this.email = email;
  }
```

> To be able change the email, you need following
>
> 1) implement methods in parent class
>
> 2) optional- add call to child classes, and for usage outside the class also add some external method (without this you can still use public parent class methods)

Eg.

**in parent**

```
public void changeEmail(String newEmail) {
          this.email = newEmail;          
}

public String changeEmailWithReturnOld(String newEmail) {
          String oldMail = this.email;
          changeEmail(newEmail); //calling above
          return oldMail;
}
```

**In childs**

```
public String changeTheMailWithReturnOld(String newMail) {
        return super.changeEmailWithReturnOld(newMail); //super means super class, parent
}
```

Clear? :)

Then you can call following:

```
Teacher teacher1 = new Teacher("foo", "foo@foo.foo", "whateverFoo");
teacher1.changeEmail("someNewFoo@foo.foo"); //parent method
teacher1.changeEmailWithReturnOld("someNewFoo@foo.foo"); //Child method
```